# Brownian motion as a rough path

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, rough-path-theory

I'm reading through the Fritz and Hairer book on Rough Path Theory and naturally want to know that a Brownian rough path or enhanced Brownian motion yields a rough path.

By the classical Kolmogorov criterium I know that for almost every $\omega\in\Omega$ the path $t\mapsto B.(\omega)$ is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous for any $\alpha<1/2$.

If I now define the second order process/object $\mathbb{B}:[0,T]^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via Itô integration, that is define

$$\mathbb{B}^{Itô}_{s,t}:=\int_s^t B_rdB_r-B_sB_{s,t}$$ where the Integral is made sense of as Itô-integral. How do I know that I obtain an $\alpha$-Rough Path?

The Hölder condition on $\mathbb{B}^{Itô}_{s,t}$ can be verified via a Kolmogorov argument and thus one only needs to verify the algebraic condition, i.e. Chen's relation.

Chen's relation for $\mathbb{B}^{Itô}_{s,t}$ now clearly holds in $L^2(\Omega)$ due to the additive nature of the stochastic integral, but I need Chen's relation to hold almost surely. How can this we shown when the integrals aren't even defined in an almost sure sense but only in $L^2(\Omega)$? Or is it possible to show the additivity of the stochastic integral to hold almost surely even though the stochastic integral is only defined in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Comment: This question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4274608/sde-almost-sure dives further into the problem, but doesn't completely answer it.

Answer (score 1):

This is further mentioned in "3.2 Ito Brownian motion" in the ["a course on rough paths"](https://www.hairer.org/notes/RoughPaths.pdf):

The $\mathbb{B}_{s,t}:=\int_{s}^{t}B_{s,r}\otimes dB_{r}$ satisfies the Chen relation on an event of probability one. They basically do this by (re)defining the increment $\mathbb{B}_{s,t}$ in terms of $\mathbb{B}_{0,\cdot}$

$$\mathbb{B}_{s,t} =\mathbb{B}_{0,t} -\mathbb{B}_{0,s} − B_s \otimes B_{s,t}.$$

This variable is defined almost surely (as is any $L^2$-Cauchy limit) and as you mentioned it satisfies the Chen relation's by breaking the integral into $\int_{s}^t=\int_{s}^u+\int_{y}^t$.

In ["Lecture 27. Approximation of the Brownian rough path"](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/lecture-27-approximation-of-the-brownian-rough-path/), the author even obtains an *almost sure* convergence to the above rough path in the p-variation norm by using the interpolation of Brownian motion.

As mentioned here [What is the explicit obstruction to almost sure convergence in stochastic integrals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076186/what-is-the-explicit-obstruction-to-almost-sure-convergence-in-stochastic-integr)
one can even have almost sure convergence in the Ito-integral.

> If the meshes are chosen regularly with meshwidth $h_n\to 0$ such that
> $$
>  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[
>  \int_{0}^{1}(f(\omega,x)-f(\omega,\lfloor x/h_n\rfloor h_n)^{2}\;dx\right]<\infty, $$ then the
> Itô sums converge almost surely to the Itô integral (under usual conditions on the integrand)
> This is proven, for example, in Remark 7.7 of the textbook [Brownian motion](https://www.hairer.org/notes/RoughPaths.pdf) by Mörters and Peres. It is an immediate consequence of Itô's isometry.
> In particular, if $f$ is $1/2+\epsilon$ Hölder continuous, then $h_n=n^{-1}$ guarantees pathwise convergence.