# SDE-almost sure

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, rough-path-theory

Let $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion. And let $s\leq u\leq t$
Does it then hold that almost surely
$$\int_s^uB_rdB_r+\int_u^tB_rdB_r=\int_s^tB_rdB_r?$$
That is for a.e. $\omega\in\Omega$
$$\bigg(\int_s^uB_rdB_r\bigg)(\omega)+\bigg(\int_u^tB_rdB_r\bigg)(\omega)=\bigg(\int_s^tB_rdB_r\bigg)(\omega)?$$
The question why I am asking this is because this property holds in $L^2(\Omega)$ but does it hold almost surely?

Comment: Does this perhaps work as follows: There exists sequencences $(X_n),(Y_n),(Z_n)$ such that $X_n\rightarrow\int_s^uB_rdB_r $ in $L^2$, $Y_n\rightarrow\int_u^tB_rdB_r $ in $L^2$, $Z_n\rightarrow\int_s^uB_rdB_r $ in $L^2$. Furthermore there exists a (sub-sub-)subsequence such that $(X_n)_k\rightarrow\int_s^uB_rdB_r $ almost surely, $(Y_n)_k\rightarrow\int_u^tB_rdB_r $ almost surely, $(Z_n)_k\rightarrow\int_s^uB_rdB_r $ almost surely. And now only has to show $(X_n)_k+(Y_n)_k=(Z_n)_k$ so one has to find a specific approximating sequence of simple functions.

Comment: And $(X_n)_k+(Y_n)_k=(Z_n)_k$ since these are simple functions.

Comment: What does it mean for this property to hold in $L^2(\Omega)$?  Here "this property" is $X+Y=Z$ for some random variables $X,Y,Z$, so what would it mean for that property to hold in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Comment: If $\mathsf{E}|X+Y-Z|^2=0$ then $X+Y=Z$ a.s.

Comment: When you fix an $\omega$, this stops being a "stochastic" question to an extent, it becomes a question of whether there exists a realisation of $B_t(\omega)$ for which your identity does not hold true.

Comment: If your integral is a Riemann sum that considers a supremum over partitions (with mesh tending to zero?), the only way for the right-hand side object to differ from the left-hand side object is if the left-hand side object was larger. The sum of the suprema is larger than the suprema of the sum.

If the mesh indeed tends to zero, it would be tough to think of a counterexample. Something like, what if the Brownian motion realisation escaped to infinity at $u$, if that is even allowed